Polarization Derivation
Can how I can find the phi and theta unit vectors as described (Eq. 4a and 4b) in the following paper on antenna cross polarization? I thought the thetha and phi unit vectors were the same as those of spherical coordinates, but that's not correct. Could someone explain how these unit vectors are determined? Here's the link to the paper: The Definition of Cross Polarization
The equation I'm referencing is:












Which refers to the second column of this diagram:













Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This may help. https://nextphasemeasurements.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/1999ESTEC_Newell-1.pdf

@Jason That was very helpful. Thank you!

Ludwig is a projection of rectangular coordinates (H/V polarization) onto a sphere. The different projections are how you slice the sphere while measuring.
Different antenna orientations and rotational axes require different "cuts" which give different unit vectors.
Here's the measurement setup that would yield Ludwig-2 coordinates:

For posterity, this is the setup that would yield Ludwig-3:

Source:
ANTENNA SPHERICAL COORDINATE SYSTEMS AND THEIR APPLICATION IN COMBINING
RESULTS FROM DIFFERENT ANTENNA ORIENTATIONS

In both these cases, would θ and Φ be the same as those in spherical coordinates? I.E. θ  is rotation from +z direction and Φ is rotation about y-axis.

Well, theta/phi are strictly spherical coordinates. Ludwig-3 uses Az/El or H/V (as in that paper). E_h an E_v are not the same as E_theta, E_phi.
